# relation of probability and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly normally distributed $(X,Y) \in \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. Is the following always correct
$$
P(X \leq a, X + Y \leq b) = E(P(X \leq a, X + Y \leq b|X))
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here are the details
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \leq a, X + Y \leq b) &=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq a, X + Y \leq b  \}}) \\
&=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq a, X + Y \leq b  \}}|X)) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(X \leq a, X + Y \leq b|X))
\end{align}$$
And the statement holds true for all random variables $X,Y$ (not necessarily follows joint normal distribution).